# EasyXls getValue() which returns the result of the formula

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to import an Excel file (using easyxls) which contains cells with formulas like '=3*5',
now I would like to get 15 as the value of the cell during the import.

Does anyone know how to get the formula result and not the formula itself from the excel cells?

What I tried so far
`cell.getValue()`.. returns the formula for the formula cells, not the result
`cell.getFormulaResultValue()` ... this is what I thought should work, but it always returns '#N/A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell.getFormulaResultValue()` is the method that you need to use, but you need to calculate the sheet first with `worksheet.easy_computeFormulas()` method.

```
table.easy_getCell("A1").setValue("=3*5");
worksheet.easy_computeFormulas(workbook, true);
table.easy_getCell("A1").getFormulaResultValue();
```

Check also this code sample about [get formula result in Excel cell](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/excel-calculation-engine.html) with EasyXLS.